# How can I get particles to collide with objects?

Tags: particles

I want my particles to form a pyramid on the ground; how can I do that?
- It seems not possible, how can i make them settle in a cup or somethign like that; i mean the settings to put for cup's plane or any tip.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Saying it's "urgent"  won't make answers come any faster; in fact, it might someone not want to answer it.

Comment: this is not a duplicate he needs the particles to collide with each other in order to form a pile  which i think needs the use of some addon

Comment: @Chebhou thanks buddy, that's what i wanted to explain

Comment: the Molecular/CubeSurfer addons may be of interest to you, https://www.youtube.com/user/PyroEvil/videos

Comment: thanks @MarcClintDion it will nicer from you if you give more details, i am new to blender and molecular add-on. i am thinking to shift all my animations to blender, no SW anymore. So now, i use what Johnny said in the answer? or the settings will change?

Comment: I don't use the Addons, I only follow the progress occasionally.  There is more info on the following two threads.  You can ask the author questions directly on the threads.  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?352233-BETA-CubeSurfer-addon-%28mesher%29 and http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?290587-Molecular-addon-available-v1-0-2-for-Blender-2-71  Feel free to return here and answer your own question if you make any progress. :)

Comment: please last little "stupid" question :), i imported my parts from SW and now i can't see any colors on my parts, they are gray. how can i bring back colors.

Comment: any answer for the colors on blender?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to form a pyramid from particles I recommend that you use keyed physics.

[image: simple]

Here are my particle settings

Pyramid's particle settings called Initial
[image: partice system of pyramid]

Cube's particle settings called Main

Start frame: 1, end frame:100, lifetime: 250

[image: particle system of cube 1]

[image: particle system of cube 2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried what you mentionned but the particles aren't staying on the pyramid or they are not forming a pyramid. @Johnny

Comment: are you sure you selected Physics/No (on the pyramid's particle settings)?

Comment: Yes yes: i did the same what you mentionned in your pictures. I don't know if i can make an open pyramid on the plate and then i will have to fill it so it will seem like a pile. as mentionned @Chebhou in his comment.